# Finding sum of all numbers in list -- python

Tags: python, list, addition

Im creating a program that takes input scores, adds them to a list and, using a for-loop, adds them all together displaying the total. Getting some problems though. Check it out Please..

```
scoreList = []
count = 0
score = 0
sum = 0
while score != 999:
    score = float(input("enter a score or enter 999 to finish: "))
    if score > 0 and score < 100:
        scoreList.append(score)
    elif (score <0 or score > 100) and score != 999:
        print("This score is invalid, Enter 0-100")
else:
    for number in scoreList:
        sum = sum + scoreList
print (sum)
```

Comment: ignore that count variable, its useless at this point

Comment: What does "getting some problems" mean? Does it raise an exception? Give you the wrong results for a certain set of inputs? Or what?

Comment: you can just use the `sum()` builtin, which you are shadowing with your local `sum` variable..

Comment: Is your program not supposed to accept scores of 0 or 100? Because right now with the way your conditions are set up, your program will ignore them.

Comment: As a side note, the `else` on the `while` really isn't necessary here. Because there's no `break`, you're guaranteed to hit it every time. And if you were trying to skip over cases where the user didn't give any scores (by typing `999` on the very first prompt), there's no good reason to do so; if `scoreList` is `[]`, `for number in scoreList:` is perfectly legal, and will successfully loop no times and do nothing.

Comment: As another side note, you don't need to "declare variables at the top" in Python; this isn't C.

Comment: @ShashankGupta 0 & 100! making that into a =< and => now. thanks.

Comment: @abarnert I've also been learning C++ and Visual Basic also. All these syntax rules are just floating around in my head!!

Comment: @roippi Im a beginner at this and my assignment is to use a for-loop so the sum function is out of question.

Comment: @MrAlex42: Have you learned how to write and call your own functions yet? If so, it might be good to try to write your own `mysum` function that does the same thing as `sum`, and then use it. If not… you'll get to that later, I guess.

Comment: @abarnert i literally just wrote that function in c a couple hours ago. No functions done in Python yet though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is simple:

```
for number in scoreList:
    sum = sum + scoreList
```

If you want to add each number in scoreList, you have to add `number`, not `scoreList`:

```
for number in scoreList:
    sum = sum + number
```

Otherwise, you're trying to add the whole list to `sum`, over and over, once per value. Which is going to raise a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'`… but really, there's nothing it *could* do which could be what you want.

---

A simpler solution is to use the built-in [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#sum) function. Of course that would mean you need a different variable name, so you don't hide the function. So:

```
total_score = sum(scoreList)
```